# How can I change the suggestions I get from the autocompletion of Resharper++?

Tags: c++, autocomplete, resharper, autosuggest

I bought Resharper two days ago but now I have 2 big problems with it.

1. When I type in `main`, it manually turns it into

   ```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   ```

   I really like this, but I need to change this code to

   ```
   int32_t main(int32_t argc,char* argv[])
   ```

   Does anyone know how I can change the code suggested by autocompletion?
2. The second problem is that when I type in `endl` it suggests another option first, although it is a worse match (like `_END_C_LIB_DECL` in this case):

   [image: wrong suggestion]

   instead of showing `endl` as first suggestion. Same with `std::array`. I don't want to always type in `std::endl`, how can I configure Resharper so that the first suggestion is the one that has the best match?

Comment: `main` must return `int`. Implementations are also required only to support `()` and `(int, char**)` as parameter lists.

Comment: int32_t is a typedef for int

Comment: You can't rely on that.

Comment: how so?  int32_t will always be able to hold 0

Comment: It's not about its ability to hold 0. The language requires that `main` returns `int`. If you don't return `int`, your program isn't well-formed C++. The language also doesn't guarantee that `int32_t` will be the same as `int`.

Comment: int is anything >= 16
which can hold 0 anyway int32_t can do the exact same, just because standard doesnt define them doesnt mean its not right )

Comment: The standard defines what is right. The language is defined by the standard.

Comment: int is not defined to be 32 bits on all systems. It's basically defined to be a fast, convenient size, and is usually anywhere from 16-64 bits.

Comment: Better title, fixed English, removed thanks and apologies for poor English, improved code formatting, added numbered list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contents of the `main` template can be changed using the "ReSharper | Tools | Templates Explorer" tool window.

As for the second issue, let me explain the reason behind it. ReSharper has two completion sources. The completion results which are visible at the current point are shown instantly, and the results that might require a namespace qualification or insertion of an include directive are added later (since collecting them might be slow). While adding these additional completion items, ReSharper can't change the selected completion item - that's why `endl` gets shown as the second item.

Comment: thank you for your help, guess i have to live with it but now i know how to change main so thats cool.

Comment: This is a problem with VB.NET also and it's a big pain.  When typing out a function call if the param variable I'm sending is named the same as the receiving param variable I get "recParmVar :=" first, then second is a suggestion for the variable name i'm trying to send.  Now for each parameter in a function call, i have to either type the full name of the var i'm sending, or type  a few characters, hit down arrow, then enter.  I would rather just turn off the function param suggestion altogether.

Comment: For future me and others, I found a way around this.  Type the partial name of the source var and press space.  The autofill will use the var name, not the "var :=" option.